# How to represent an object with a key that can be one of several strings?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with an API that returns json that looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": "2342342-2341-23412-34",
  "name": "some name",

  "foo": {
    "address": "112333343234234"
  }
}
```

But, the key "foo" can only be one of three strings: `foo`, `bar`, `baz`. There will only ever be one of these key-value pairs on an object. The structure of the value will always be `{ address: string }`.

What is the best way to represent this type? Something like this (but obviously this doesn't work):

```
type ItemResponse = {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'?: {
    address: string;
  }
};
```

I also tried this, also does not work:

```
type ItemResponse = {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  [K in ['foo' | 'bar' | 'baz']]?: { address: string };
}
```

**NOTE THAT THIS QUESTION IS ALSO ABOUT THE KEY VALUE, NOT JUST ENFORCEMENT OF A SINGLE KEY**

Comment: Seems like you want a union `{ foo: ... } | { bar: ... } | { baz: ... }`.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for an approach to this

Comment: @jcalz be sure you actually read the question and understand it before you mark as a duplicate.

Comment: I can assure you I actually read the question and understood it before I marked it as a duplicate.  Using the answer there with the example here produces [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wOr9EW), which, unless I am mistaken, is exactly the behavior you're asking for.  If you can demonstrate that I am indeed mistaken I would be more than happy to vote to reopen. I can also assure you that my intent with moderation is in good faith, and I would hope that you could assume such good faith when interacting with others.

Comment: Again, if you can demonstrate that I am mistaken about the closure, and that [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wOr9EW) does not do what you want, I would be very willing to vote to reopen.  That code is as close to an answer specifically tailored to your question as I can make, but if I wrote it up as an answer it would be essentially a duplicate of the other answer.  Please, instead of complaining about Stack Overflow, which is essentially off-topic and not anything I can do anything about, try to *demonstrate* that the closure is in error. But if you're just looking to vent, I can unfollow.

Comment: My question is "How to represent an object with a key that can be one of several strings" and the other one is "Enforce Typescript object has exactly one key from a set". The question is different, has different requirements, requirements that are not talked about in the other question. I did not find the other question when searching before I posted mine. If the question is different, and the answer just happens to apply to both, is the question a duplicate? Doesn't matter, you didn't ask for any clarification. You're more worried about moderating than helping, and that is the essence of SO.

Comment: Sorry for the unpleasant interaction. I suppose we're hopelessly at an impasse. If my previous comments were not sufficient to establish that I am indeed interested in helping (e.g. I spent time and effort making a [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOr9EW) tailored specifically to your question) then further communication is unlikely to improve the situation. If you disagree with the closure reason, please vote to reopen.  I will not respond to further comments here.